# How to get an in input value after a DOM injection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i'm doing a function that inject some HTML to the dom after an ajax function this way.

**The function that inject HTML**

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: base_url + "main/GetTheLastSeq"
                  })
           .done(function( msg1 ) {
            console.log(ii);
            $('#ch').append(msg1);
            ii++;

           });
```

**2nd function trying to manipulate the injected HTML**

```
$(".item").on("click","i", function(){
 var id = $("#idh").val();
 alert(id);
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data : {id:id},
            url: base_url + "main/Deleteseq"
                  })
           .done(function( msg) {
            alert(msg);

           });
});
```

The HTML :

[image]

i'm trying to get the value of in input injected after this ajax function. ther `alert(id);` return me a blank value.

Any help please

Thanks

Comment: show your html as well

Comment: $("#idh").val(); <-- I don't see an element with this ID in your HTML

Comment: I can't see an element with the class of `$(".item")` 'item' (It's above the source code?) or an id '#idh' in your HTML?

Comment: they exist i've just cropped the image well

Comment: `#idh` has no value, why would `.val()` not return blank ?

Comment: 1131 is not a value ?

Comment: @K.Ly no, it is not. Value of `input` is set by `<input value="1131">`.

Comment: @K.Ly see my answer below..

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the hidden content into `value=""` tags... like this:

```js
$('button[name=showval]').click(function(){
  alert($('input[name=hiddenval]').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" value="Some hidden value!" name="hiddenval"/>
<button name="showval">Show the hidden value!</button>
```

Greetings from Austria